# Unpacking <select> fields with gorilla/schema

Tags: html, go, gorilla

I'm using [gorilla/schema](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema) to unpack `r.PostForm` into a struct.

My issue is that I'm trying to figure out a "sensible" way to get the selected value of a `<select>` element in a way that allows me to easily use `html/template` to re-select the field (i.e. when re-populating the form from a session) noting that there isn't an easy way to test for equality *and* just by passing an instance of the struct to `RenderTemplate`.

To illustrate what I have:

```
type Listing struct {
    Id           string        `schema:"-"`
    Title        string        `schema:"title"`
    Company      string        `schema:"company"`
    Location     string        `schema:"location"`
        ...
    Term         string        `schema:"term"`
}
```

---

```
if r.Method == "POST" {

// error handling code removed for brevity, but trust me, it exists!

    err = r.ParseForm()
    err = decoder.Decode(listing, r.PostForm)
    err = listing.Validate() // checks field lengths as I'm using a schema-less datastore
```

---

```
<label for="term">Term</label>
      <select data-placeholder="Term...?" id="term" name="term" required>
        <option name="term" value="full-time">Full Time</option>
        <option name="term" value="part-time">Part Time</option>
        <option name="term" value="contract">Contract</option>
        <option name="term" value="freelance">Freelance</option>
      </select>
```

---

... and what I want to be able to do when I pass an instance of listing to the template:

```
renderTemplate(w, "create_listing.tmpl", M{
        "listing":              listing,
    })
```

---

```
 <label for="term">Term</label>
          <select data-placeholder="Term...?" id="term" name="term" required>
            <option name="term" value="full-time" {{ if .term == "full-time" }}selected{{end}}>Full Time</option>
            <option name="term" value="part-time"{{ if .term == "part-time" }}selected{{end}}>Part Time</option>
            <option name="term" value="contract" {{ if .term == "contract" }}selected{{end}}>Contract</option>
            <option name="term" value="freelance" {{ if .term == "freelance" }}selected{{end}}>Freelance</option>
          </select>
```

Obviously this won't work. I've considered `template.FuncMap` as a possible solution but I'm not sure how I can use this when I want to pass the entire listing instance to the template (i.e. instead of field-by-field). I also want to, if possible, minimise unnecessary fields in my struct. I could have boolean fields for each value (i.e. `Fulltime bool`, but I then need code to change the other fields to "false" if the user goes back and edits things.

Is there a way to achieve this in way that meshes well with the limitations of `template/html`?

Comment: I recommend repopulating forms using JS when possible.

Comment: @tomwilde I can't re-populate across views though, unless I store the data in a cookie w/ JS. Which is insecure, and my gobbed `<textarea>` exceeds the 4K cookie limit.

Comment: You can output the values as JSON into a <script> block or load them asynchronously through AJAX after page load.

Comment: True, but it's not going to be quick given a relatively large (up to 2,000 word) text field and will likely result in a flash of empty fields while it loads. Users will typically hit form > preview, and then go back to the form if they need to make adjustments. Since I store it all in the session, I can just `delete()` it when submitted else let the session expiry take care of it. Also allows me to validate the form in-between steps.

JS solutions to this seem so flaky (but if you know a good lib, I'll still take a look). I based my design on the Django form impl, which is quite solid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a view to build and represent a `select` element:

```
{{define "select"}}
    <select name="{{.Name}}>
        {{range $a, $b := .Options}}
             <option value="{{print $a}}" {{if $a == .Selected}}>{{print $b}}</option>
        {{end}}
    </select>
{{end}}
```

And the corresponding data structure:

```
type SelectBlock struct {
    Name     string
    Selected string
    Options  map[string]string
}
```

Then instantiate it:

```
termSelect := SelectBlock{
    Name:     "term",
    Selected: "",
    Options:  map[string]string{
        "full-time": "Full Time",
        "part-time": "Part Time",
        "contract":  "Contract",
        "freelance": "Freelance",
    },
}
```

And set the `Selected` field:

```
termSelect.Selected = "full-time"
```

And output the view fragment inside your form view:

```
{{template "select" $termSelect}}
```

Where `$termSelect` would be your instance of `SelectBlock`.

Comment: Thanks to `cronos` in #go-nuts, I'm using Go 1.2RC2, which includes an equality operator (!): http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#text_template

Given that your answer is one of the "better" ways to do this in Go 1.1.x, alongside an [eq() FuncMap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/vQfqhTszj4c) or  using [reflect.DeepEquals](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/OEdSDgEC7js) I'm going to accept this as the answer. Thanks for your help on this @tomwilde.

Answer (score 2):

For others looking at this in the future, who are using Go v1.2 or later: `text/template` and `html/template` now offer an equality operator (amongst other new operators): http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#text_template

```
{{if eq .Term "full-time" }}selected{{end}}
...
{{if eq .Term "freelance" }}selected{{end}}
```